# How to create mysql database table for dynamic fields

Tags: mysql

I want to create database table using mysql for transport application. Here I want to add columns which are not fixed for every record. They are added dynamically for every record. For example, record 1 contains **PoliceFees** & **StateBoundry** whereas record 2 does not have these fields. record 3 might have some others fields and so on. So how to design table for such data??

Comment: Set default value to `NULL`, for the fields which may be empty

Comment: Use JSON data to store the 'optional' values. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic fields and MySQL (relational database)? I think no-SQL is a better solution to your problem.

But if that fields is all known you can create a table with all of them and set as nullable. So you only insert needed data.